# Is there an easy wrapper to sync an array of documents between memory and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to implement a moderation dashboard. Users post listings continuously and an Admin would delete or modify new unapproved Listings (approves a listing finally).

I found [this amazing library](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jammin-salmon) the sync HTTP front and back magically.
As you can see, all data is backed in-memory in an array. I would like to keep the data synchronised based on ID in the MongoDB collection. Obviously, I can go through the implementation of each HTTP method, but this would be easier if any solution exists already.

Here a part of my longer code. I'm fulfilling each HTTP method: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH.

```
// CLONE BASE DATA LIST
let realtimeJSON
// TODO: secure, but doubleSecure (admin)
router.get('/admin', async function (req, res, next) {
  const listings = await mongoQueries.getDocumentsForApproval()
  realtimeJSON = listings.documents
  // realtimeJSON.forEach((a, idx) => a.id = idx+1)
  res.send(realtimeJSON)
})

router.get('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
  res.render('admin', {})
})

// CREATE
router.post('/admin/', function (request, response) {
  console.log('--- POST 200 ---')
  realtimeJSON.push(request.body)
  // Return list
  response.send(realtimeJSON)
})
...
```

The array is `realtimeJSON`.

Comment: I guess this can be achieved easily with [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

Comment: Why don't you just update the database each time you modify the in-memory array?  Then, the DB is always up to date rather than letting it get stale and then trying to reverse engineer what changed and synchronize.

Comment: I'm, I am just looking for some wrapper that do GET, POST, PATCH, PUT for me, because all are predictable here no filters or projections... I found `updateMany`, I will look later how to choose the right parameters for performance.

Comment: Well, mongodb offers a Javascript library for interfacing from nodejs so there's no need for you to do GET, POST, PATCH or PUT directly to the database.  You would have to add code into each incoming http transaction and then update the database accordingly by calling its API.  I doubt you're going to find anything that does that automatically.

Comment: I guess one single `find` and `updateMany` would achieve this. Again, I'm only not sure about `updateMany` performance

Comment: Well, I suggested your not try to sync the entire array, but rather handle each incoming transaction one at a time to update the database with each transaction so you're not doing sync, but just handling incremental changes as they arrive.  Not sure you need `updateMany()` for that unless the incoming transactions are affecting multiple records at once.

Comment: indeed, no need to keep the array at all. But I need to `find` documents on each operation which is OK

Comment: The array can be useful as an in-memory cache if that's a worthwhile performance boost, but it is required that you keep the database up-to-date or you run into chances of losing data if you're server crashes for any reason and you haven't yet updated it.